# jquerymobile Thumbnails

Tags: jquery-mobile

salam

i'm new in jqueryMobile and i want to view a Thumbnails but a got this[image]

how can i got a normal one?

here the code of this list

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
        {% for produit in produits %}   

            <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="index.html" class="ui-link-inherit">
                {% if produit.Images is empty %}
                    <img src="{{asset('upload/non_disponible.jpg')}}" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
                {% else %}
                    <img src="{{asset('upload/')}}{{produit.Images[0].path}}" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
                {% endif %}
                <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Broken Bells</h3>
                <p class="ui-li-desc">Broken Bells</p>
            </a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>

        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code instead (using jQuery Mobile version 1.2.0):

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">

    {% for produit in produits %}   
    <li data-theme="c">
        <a href="index.html" class="ui-link-inherit">
            {% if produit.Images is empty %}
                <img src="{{asset('upload/non_disponible.jpg')}}" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
            {% else %}
                <img src="{{asset('upload/')}}{{produit.Images[0].path}}" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
            {% endif %}
            <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Broken Bells</h3>
            <p class="ui-li-desc">Broken Bells</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    {%endfor%}

</ul>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know about your results.